# What is the primary use case of AWS STS GetFederationToken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sts

Referring to this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html#api_getfederationtoken), there are 5 APIs to retrieve credentials using STS:

1. `AssumeRole`
2. `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`
3. `AssumeRoleWithSAML`
4. `GetFederationToken`
5. `GetSessionToken`

`AssumeRole` is useful for managing permissions centrally using IAM roles. Web identity and SAML federation are also straightforward. `GetSessionToken` is useful to protect sensitive IAM users and to protect connections from insecure locations, especially using MFA. I have also used this in the past.

However, what is the main purpose for `GetFederationToken`, in comparison to `AssumeRole`? The article seems to suggest the key difference is that it allows for a substantially longer expiration. Is this really the primary purpose of this API? Why is it crucial to have a different API just for longer expiration?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few difference between `AssumeRole` and `GetFederationToken` apart from expiration.

`AssumeRole` obviously requires a role with policies. `GetFederationToken` is called by the credentials of an IAM user, and it doesn't involve roles. `GetFederationToken` is more similar to `GetSessionToken` but with session policy support. Also the restrictions on resulting temporary credentials are different, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html#stsapi_comparison).

Use case for `GetFederationToken`: creating temporary credentials from IAM user with session policy when there is no role to assume.

Answer (score 0):

GetFederationToken is better for scenarios where you're dealing with users authenticated by external systems, and you're not managing those external accounts directly. AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity is better for accounts/identity providers you manage directly.